# Looking for the Formula for Uncertainty for Velocity

Tags: velocity, error-analysis

In a lab I'm working on, we used a formula for uncertainty of area:

$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{δl}{l}\right)^2+\left(\frac{δw}{w}\right)^2}$$

We are asked to now find uncertainty for velocity (m/s) and the hint was to use the same formula above, but I'm not sure how.  This is my only guess, but it seems odd and incorrect to me:

$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{δm}{m}\right)^2+\left(\frac{δs}{s}\right)^2}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Very odd. One is a product, and one is a ratio--so maybe it works if you measure velocity in meter-Hertz (which is fine). Try some calculus and see tell us what you think.

Comment: Yes, it is odd.  The professor specifically said "the same formula that works with multiplication also works with division."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you do:

Start with the area formula (no explanation needed):
$$ A = lw $$

Add the derivatives in quadrature:

$$ (dA)^2 = (l\cdot dw)^2 + (w \cdot dl)^2 $$

Use the area formula's inverses:

$$ (dA)^2 = \left(\frac A w dw\right)^2 + \left(\frac A l \cdot dl\right)^2 $$

Divide by $A^2$ and take the square root:

$$ \frac{dA}A = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dw}w\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dl}l\right)^2 }$$

So that checks out. This is now in a "relative error form"--that is, e.g., a 10% error in length gives a 10% error in area--makes sense.

So if I do it in meter-Hertz:

$$ v = xf $$

(distance $x$ times frequency $f$). I can safely say:

$$ dv = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}x\right)^2 + \left(\frac{df}f\right)^2 }$$

Then I just need to convert $df/f$ to a seconds based result--since it's a relative error, I suspect it should work--a 10% error in frequency should have the same (up to sign and to 1st order) effect as a 10% error in time--and we don't care about sign because we're adding in quadrature:

$$ f = \frac 1 T $$

$$ df = \frac{-dT}{T^2} $$

so that

$$ \frac{df}{f} = \frac{\frac{-dT}{T^2}}{\frac 1 T} = -\frac{dT} T$$

Your professor was right.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll mull over this for a few minutes, but it seems logical.

Answer (score 1):

The error formula for a product and for a ratio **is** the same if you write it in terms of relative errors.

The general combination of uncorrelated errors formula for $f(x,y)$ is

$\sigma_f^2=\left({\partial f \over \partial x}\right)^2 \sigma_x^2+\left({\partial f \over \partial y}\right)^2 \sigma_y^2$

For the special case $f=xy$ this is $\sigma_f^2 = y^2 \sigma_x^2+x^2 \sigma_y^2$, which can be made to look prettier by dividing throughout by $f$ (using $f=xy$ on the RHS)

$\left({\sigma_f\over f}\right)^2 =\left({\sigma_x\over x}\right)^2 +\left({\sigma_y\over y}\right)^2 $

For the special case $f=x/y$ the formula gives

$\sigma_f^2=\left({1 \over y}\right)^2 \sigma_x^2+\left(-{x\over y^2}\right)^2 \sigma_y^2$

which looks horrible, but that minus sign goes away as it is squared, and if you again divide by $f$ on the $LHS$ and $x/y$ on the RHS what emerges is

$\left({\sigma_f\over f}\right)^2 =\left({\sigma_x\over x}\right)^2 +\left({\sigma_y\over y}\right)^2 $

the same as for the product. Which is nice - but is (I think) just a coincidence with no deep meaning, though it is handy. Other forms (sums, differences, powers) do not fit this pattern.